# Using jQuery validation, is there a way I can reset a form without having a reference to the created object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a generic jQuery validation call in  a global JS file:

```
$('form').each(function() {
    $(this).validate();
});
```

This way, any forms on the website can enable validation by simply providing metadata. However, now I want to reset the form because I'm doing AJAX submits. On the official website, it says to reset forms by using the created object:

```
var validator = $('#someForm').validate();
```

Problem is, with my generic validator setup, I don't have a reference to the created object. Is there a way I can still retrieve it in my case?

Comment: .validate() will return the validator object if it has already been created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by reset the forms. Just in case...

You can remove validation like this..

```
$("form").removeData("validator");
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
```

Comment: BTW, you can remove multiple pieces of data with a single call to `removeData` - either pass an array of strings or a space-delimited string, e.g. `$('form').removeData(['validator', 'unobtrusiveValidation']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this ,

```
function ResetValidations(){
           $("form").removeData("validator");
           $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
           $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var formValidations = [];
$('form').each(function() {
    formValidations.push($(this).validate());
});
```

Then iterate through `formValidations`

```
for(var i in formValidations)
{
    //do something with formValidations[i]
}
```