# How to write Validation code based on fieldsets that are currently visible using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

We need to retrieve all the required fields in this codeIgniter/PHP app, since the hide/display js code is used, how can I, using jquery, get all the required fields that are visible? see attached sample html.

In the prod app, all the required fields have this css on the label [ * ]. is there a way to pull all these fields using jquery? Here is the catch, issue, this [ * ] is on the label, I actually need get/check that the associate field is empty and the field could be a text, dropdown, checbox, radio, etc. if empty, I need prevent submission of the form and display error message.

In short, **OnClick** of the submit button, grab **all fields that are required** that are **in fieldsets that are currently visible** [has to do with detecting height and width] if any of these fields are empty, stop form submission and display error message, ie:
"this field is required" 
"this field is required" 
"this field is required" [This will go into a div at the top of the page]

**test code below:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Project Overview</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var projectType_Field_Id = '1169';

//Project Types
var projectTypes = new Array (
    {id : '11', value:'Cars'},
    {id : '12', value:'Boats'},
    {id : '13', value:'Planes'});

//occurs onLoad
function formOnLoad()
{
    var project_type = document.getElementById(projectType_Field_Id).value;
    refreshSections(project_type);
    }
/*
 *  Onchange - Project Type
 */
function projectTypeChange()
{ 
    var project_type = document.getElementById(projectType_Field_Id).value;
    refreshSections(project_type);
}

function refreshSections(selectedType) 
{    
    for (var i = 0; i < projectTypes.length; i++) 
    {
        if (projectTypes[i].value == selectedType) 
        {
            document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="formOnLoad();">
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset name="mainSection">
                <legend style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Project Overview Section</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px; color:maroon">Name<span class="required"> * </span></td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1125" name="1125" type="text" class="valuetext fld_required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px; color:maroon">Email<span class="required"> * </span></td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1026" name="1026" type="text" class="valuetext fld_required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Title</td>
                        <td><input  id="1089" name="1089" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Type</td>
                        <td><select id="1169" name="1169"  onChange="projectTypeChange();">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
                        <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </table>
            </fieldset><br /><br />

            <fieldset id="section-11" name="section-11">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Car Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label style="color:maroon">Size:</label><span class="required"> * </span></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" class="valuetext fld_required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                            <br />
            <fieldset id="section-12" name="section-12">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Plane Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label  style="color:maroon">Size:</label><span class="required"> * </span></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1254" name="1254" type="radio" class="valuetext fld_required"/>Small
                        <input id="1254" name="1254" type="radio" />Large</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset><br />
            <fieldset id="section-13" name="section-13">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Boat Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label  style="color:maroon">Size:</label><span class="required"> * </span></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><select id="1245[]" name="1245[]" class="valuetext fld_required">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Small">Small</option>
                        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="Large">Large</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
<fieldset id="section-1011" name="section-1011">
                <legend style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Misc Info Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1301" name="1301" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1302" name="1302">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1303" name="1303" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                            <input name="Send Job" type="submit" value="Send Job" />

</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you have the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to find everything that is visible

```
$("form > :visible")
```

then you can use the [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method from JQuery to find out what element it is ... and do whatever you want with them.

Alternatively you can use [JQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) add some rules to the controls and if you disable them they will automatically not be validated, if they are re-enabled you can do what they do in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816217/336542).

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the html a little bit, the easiest way (IMO) would be to put a "required" class on the required fields themselves and not on the labels.
Then, you could select them with

```
$("fieldset:visible *.required").each(function() {
... check if $(this) is empty and display a message if necessary...
})
```

Comment: ok, I have add an additional class:class="valuetext fld_required". so now all fields that are required have the above class structure

Comment: I have created this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/CtVpu/18/- not working perfectly, but could you add the code into it.  It is just not working for me.

Comment: Your jsfiddle returns a 404 to me. I also see in your example you do not include the jquery library (but maybe you just omitted it in the copy-paste). You should also add your onsubmit handler on the form with the code I proposed in my answer. You could take a look at karim 's answer which seems quite complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {

    // get the empty elements of the visible fieldsets
    var $empties = $("fieldset:visible").find(":input").filter(function () {

        // for me, a blank space is empty
        // remove the $.trim() if that's not the case
        return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
    });

    // put some error messages somewhere
    if ($empties.length) {
        $empties.each(function () {

            // I am assuming the "name" attribute is meaningful
            $("#errorDiv").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
        });
    }

    // only submit if there are no empties
    return !$empties.length;
});
```